# Проблемы с Genymotion и Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

Пытаюсь сделать внешний эмулятор для Android Studio, но выдает ошибку.

Машину смог создать, но `Genymotion` ругается:

[image: ошибка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> 00:00:35.322490 ********************* End of statistics **********************
>   00:00:35.325634 TxTimer stats (avg/min/max):       0 usec      -1 usec       0 usec
>   00:00:35.326423 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_cluster, used:0)
>   00:00:35.326881 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_packet, used:0)
>   00:00:35.326889 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf, used:0)
>   00:00:35.326980 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_pagesize, used:0)
>   00:00:35.327507 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_9k, used:0)
>   00:00:35.328028 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_16k, used:0)
>   00:00:35.328281 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_ext_refcnt, used:0)
>   00:00:35.328344 TxTimer stats (avg/min/max):       0 usec      -1 usec       0 usec
>   00:00:35.330267 Changing the VM state from 'DESTROYING' to 'TERMINATED'
>   00:00:35.330913 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'

Comment: Версия какая? С недавних пор GenyMotion платный

Comment: @Barmaley обновил вопрос

Comment: Запустите виртуальную машину (девайс) в VirtualBox (откройте его отдельно) и посмотрите, что он вам скажет в логах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему активацией Intel Virtual Technology в BIOS